# Power BI - Model Object Names must be non empty

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-mobile

I made few changes in the query editor. But when I close and apply the changes. I get the error Model object names must be non empty. I tried deleting the last changes I made in query editor. The error still exists.

Comment: I encountered same error and it turns out the result generated a column without name.

Answer (score 1):

In Power Bi, this error is saying you have empty columns in your data set.  You have to delete that columns and refresh the document and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

@HuaGong is correct. Most likely one or more columns are loaded without a name.

Answer (score 0):

This says that you have left one Column heading blank.
Delete the column or give a name to the column.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you enable "Use First Row as a header" and there are null values in the first row.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if the Excel (other source document you are using) is open on your desktop. You have to close the document and then try again.